# How to change "drawableLeft" when focus status changed?

Tags: java, android

[image]

1.I don't want to write too many selector to each component.

2.I tried to write a subclass of EditText named it EditTextDrawable. Then I did like this:

```
public EditTextWithDrawable(Context context, final Drawable normal, final Drawable focus){
    super(context);
    setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // changeDrawable(hasFocus, normal, focus);
        }
    });
```

But if I want to reset the OnFocusChangeListener, I have to type the code again. It's boring.

Is there a simple way to solve this? tks advanced!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(fous, null, null, null);
    }else {
        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(normal, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: OnFocusChangeListener is an Interface so the super is invalid. So I have to write a class A to implement the Interface. And the when set FocusChangelistener I can only use the class A instead of the Interface. any other way?